# Extract data from .json file in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an angular application.  I can load the .json file into the application but I can't figure out the syntax for access the data in the file.  I posted a similar question on this topic but I may have been too broad,  I simply need to know how to access the data in a file I already have uploaded and that my application recognizes as application/json file

```
 startUpload(event: FileList){

    var file = event.item(0);

    console.log(file)    


  }
```

console output

```
File(139404) {name: "turnaroundtest.json", lastModified: 1527392751758, lastModifiedDate: Sat May 26 2018 20:45:51 GMT-0700 (PDT), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 139404, …}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
  detectFiles(event) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = ((e) => {
        const result = e.target['result'];
        console.log(JSON.parse(result));
      });
      reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

`console.log('name' + jsonObject.name);` 
**or**

```
if (undefined !== jsonResponse.name && null !== jsonResponse.name){
    console.log('name' + jsonResponse.name);
}
```

if you have array of json then

```
for (const jsonObject in jsonResponse) {
    if (undefined !== jsonResponse[jsonObject].name && null !== jsonResponse[jsonObject].name) {
        console.log('name' + jsonResponse[jsonObject].name);
    }
}
```